# Do paused downloads still have an impact on Internet or Wifi speed?

Tags: xbox-one, networking

I've heard that pausing downloads won't effect your Wifi but I want to be sure.

Is this the case? I just want some clarification for the future

Comment: yes, pausing the download creates a temporary index of data on your machine, it uses this information when you resume the download as the basis for communicating a partial download, so no data has to be sent across the internet once it's paused

Comment: This doesn't really seem on-topic, since it's really a question about networking and is only tangentially related to gaming.

Comment: Slowing down your Wifi versus the speed at which your ISP delivers your internet at versus bandwidth are all different things.  I suspect what you are really talking about is bandwidth.

Comment: Since the question is specifically asking about the way in which an Xbox One functions, I think this is on-topic enough.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about basic networking principles, not anything related to gaming.

Comment: @Frank - Game specific hardware is on-topic. This question is literally about Xbox One's handling of paused downloads; extrapolating from that it's about *'When'* and *'Why'* (but not 'How') the Xbox will call out over the network. This has nothing to do with "networking principles", basic or otherwise.

Comment: @Robotnik The only reference we have to anything gaming specific is a tag.  Everything else is straight up networking.  A tag isn't enough for me to assume it's gaming-specific.

Comment: @Frank - You mean like basically **every other question** on this site? Do you think that for every type of question? *"How do I defeat this dragon? [minecraft]"*, "Voting to close as off topic as dragons aren't real, that tag isn't enough for me to assume it's gaming specific"

Comment: @Robotnik Right, that's one argument.  There's also the one where new users just use any old random tag for whatever they ask, as that is a rather common occurance.  That's where I believe this falls into.  Beyond that, you see it your way, I see it mine.  We'll agree to disagree.

Comment: @Frank If it's just a random tag and the user isn't on xbox 1 then you're right that it should be closed for either **off-topic** or **unclear what you're asking**. The tag is there though, so you need to assume good faith. If you're concerned it's just a random tag then you should ask the OP to clarify if they're on xbox 1, but you shouldn't just assume the tag is irrelevant and close the question.

Comment: @Wipqozn Yeah, which is *literially what I did*.  I voted as off-topic.  As it stands, though, I'm getting seriously tired of getting bashed by you two for standing by my vote.  Enough.  I get it.  You disagree.  We're not going to agree, so can we just drop it already?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, paused downloads should not affect your Wifi.

However, note that downloads are not the only thing that will cause the Xbox One to use the internet. For example:

- The Xbox may check for updates for itself or applications & games you have installed.
- Any running applications (including games) may call out to the internet for different reasons (license checks, multiplayer sign-in, streaming data).

---

If you're worried about your Xbox slowing down your Internet/using too much data:

- Disconnect it from the Network when you aren't using Network features, and
- Turn off the Xbox when you're not using it

If you're seeing slowdowns over Wifi when using the Xbox One but your internet connection is otherwise fine, consider connecting it to your Router using an Ethernet Cable instead of Wifi.